# How to divide value of array by a constant and keeping associative keys using PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I have following array:

```
Array
(
[ALFA] => 474
[BETA] => 359
[GAMMA] => 248
[DELTA] => 147
[EPSILON] => 137
[ZETA] => 135
)
```

and would like to divide it by a constant X, for example 213, so in the end I have following array as result:

```
Array
(
[ALFA] => 2.2253
[BETA] => 1.6854
[GAMMA] => 1.1643
[DELTA] => 0.6901
[EPSILON] => 0.6431
[ZETA] => 0.6338
)
```

I'm doing this

```
foreach($array as $v){
    $newArray[] = ($v / $divisor); //in our examploe $divisor = 213.
}
```

but then the new array has indexed keys just like that:

```
Array
(
[0] => 2.2253
[1] => 1.6854
[2] => 1.1643
[3] => 0.6901
[4] => 0.6431
[5] => 0.6338
)
```

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
array_walk(
    $myArray,
    function(&$value) use ($divisor) {
        $value /= $divisor;
    }
);
```

Note that this changes the original array directly

Comment: Yep and if you want to make a new array just replace array_walk with array_map.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @MarkBaker! If I may ask, what should I do, if I want to pow or multiply the values? Just like that:
(pow($value,2) /= $divisor) * 1000 ?

Comment: If you want to use pow and multiply, then replace `$value /= $divisor;` with `$value = (pow($value,2) / $divisor) * 1000;`.... `$value /= $divisor;` is simply a shorthand for `$value = $value / $divisor;`

Comment: Very interesting this shorthand. Thank you for that as well!

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the key=>value foreach loop and specify the key of each element:

```
foreach($array as $key=>$v){
    $newArray[$key] = ($v / $divisor); //in our examploe $divisor = 213.
    //     here ^
}
```

Comment: @Billy Don't worry, there will be plenty of other chances. :)